# increase memory limit on wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have wamp64 and php version 5.6.16 and apache 2.4.17.  I have a  4gb ram win7 pc

I am running a cakephp project and keep getting an error when displaying rows from a table

> Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4145278 bytes)

To increase the memory there is no `php.ini` so I changed the  `memory_limit = 2048M` in `php-production.ini` but I'm not sure if I edited the correct file.

This has no effect as I still get the same error. Am I able to increase the memory limit and do I do this in which file? I seem to be stuck on this amount of memory 134217728

I didn't make sense of past replies on the topic as the file `php.ini` doesn't exist in this wamp

Comment: Why do you think php.ini does not exists in Wamp **PHP** directory?

Comment: I think you might be editing the incorrect PHP ini file. I'd try finding which PHP ini file is being loaded by testing out the `php -i` command then grepping the output to display the loaded configuration file. If none, then make a copy of `php-production.ini` or `php-development.ini` and rename the copy as a `php.ini` file.

Comment: I'd rather try to find out why you are hitting the memory limit and fix that code.

Comment: the code is fine it just I am using  a large db. This is windows so there is no grepp. Not sure what to do here. ALso I cant rename the php-XX.ini files as it wont let me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The php.ini file usually is on "*C:\wamp64\bin\php\php_ver" where "php_ver*" is the version of the PHP you are using (please note the latest version of wamp includes two version of PHP, make sure you edit the right php.ini file)

then on line 397 you can find `memory_limit = 128M`

change it, save it, and restart the services.

Comment: There is no php.ini in this location.

Comment: I have WAMPSERVER 3.1.0 64bit, and the php.ini is in that location

Comment: Best way to reach php.ini in WAMP is to click the tray icon > PHP > php.ini

Comment: In the most recent version of Wamp that I just installed, it was as easy as: `Wamp tray icon > PHP > PHP Settings > memory_limit > ______`

Comment: This works for me. I'm editing the wrong php.ini inside the wrong version.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm in the correct PHP version and changed it from 128 to 256. Restarted WAMP, and no change.

Answer (score 0):

I go to php-production.ini files and change the memory their. Not sure if thi is the best way but I couldnt rename the php.ini file and no one else had a better idea either

Answer (score 0):

Simply empty the logs
right click wamp -> tools -> empty logs -> empty all logs files

Comment: It didn't work, WAMP icon still brown color 

Answer (score 0):

While modifying the php.ini file in the apache directory, i had to totally close and restart wamp software, restart services was not sufficient.

Comment: @Ruvee Sorry for that, as far as i can't comment under any answer, i could not find a way to share my experience.